# I am trying to make a popup window that pops up in a random position on the screen, but it ends up in the same spot every time?

Tags: javascript

Here is the loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  var randomval =  random(0, screen.height)
  var myWindow = window.open("", ("MsgWindow", i), "width=200,height=100,top=0, left=random(0, screen.width)");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>TROLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL</p>");
```

This is the "random" function it calls to

```
function random(min, max) { // min and max included
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

Comment: `left=random(0, screen.width)` is part of a literal string. You’re not using your function at all there.

Comment: [window features of `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#window_features) does not seem to allow JavaScript.